# Responsive Colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Here is a link to my website: [www.gilliandeanna.com](http://www.gilliandeanna.com)

I've been trying to figure out how to make the colorbox responsive when you open the pictures so that they shrink depending on the device you're viewing it on.

As of right now, if you were to look at my site on a mobile device, if you click on a thumbnail to open the gallery pertaining to that thumbnail the image is the dimensions of the image itself (800 px wide). I've read through things on the internet and stack overflow and tried to paste code that I've seen into my files but it doesn't work. As soon as I try anything it makes it so that colorbox no longer works and when you click on a thumbnail it doesn't open the gallery it just opens the first picture of that gallery.

In the colorbox jQuery file, there is an option that says `scalePhotos` and I have that set to `'true'`. I also tried changing the width and height from `'false'` to `'100%'` but that just made colorbox stop working.

I'm very new to coding. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: I think it is better to create an example of the issue in codepen.io so that people can just focus on the issue and easily try different things to help you with.

Comment: I really can't afford to pay for one of their plans just to try and host my site on there for someone to play around with to fix, unfortunately. I had just been hoping that maybe someone would be able to view my website and use a tool in firefox to go "behind the scenes" and see what might be wrong and why it's not working. My website itself is responsive but when you look at it at mobile size and you go to the section w/ colorbox, when you click on a thumbnail to open the corresponding gallery the gallery is the same size as when it's viewed on a desktop. It's not responsive.

Comment: You don't need to pay anything. You don't need to put your website on codepen. You just need to reproduce the issue you are encountering with in an example. For instance, you can create an example where one thumbnail with Colorbox exists, which behaves as you said on smaller devices. It is free by the way. That's how it works here, creating a small example of the issue you have and let others to pinpoint the issue and resolve it.

Comment: Oh okay. I know I must sound like a total idiot but how can I put an example or a snippet on codepen? Like if colorbox is dependent upon the jquery file and a css file and putting just one thumbnail from my website for example would involve a bunch of other jquery and css files. I just have such limited knowledge of everything. I hate to be so annoying.

Comment: That's OK, all of us were at the same position as you are today. We learn by our mistakes and we are here to teach each other as well. You can create a free account for yourself on codepen.io  Then you can create a new pen by clicking on "New pen" where you will see four panes, namely HTML, CSS, JS, and results. As name suggests, you can have your codes for each part in the right pane. check this out     http://codepen.io/hello/

Answer (score 3):

Just checked out your JS file. Currently what you have for colorbox setup is this:

```
//gallery light box setup
$('a.colorbox').colorbox({
           rel: function(){
                  return $(this).data('group');
           }
});
```

Add this piece of code below the code above and give it a try:

```
//gallery light box setup
$('a.colorbox').colorbox({
     rel: function(){
            return $(this).data('group');
     },
     scalePhotos: true 
});

$(window).resize(function() {
   $.colorbox.resize({
       "width": $(window).width()*0.9,
       "height": $(window).height()*0.9
   });
});
```

It will resize the live colorbox to 90% of the height and width of your window sizes. Check out a working example in [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/YwOmzZ)

Comment: I tried adding that changed code and while the image that opens up once you click on a thumbnail is responsive it takes away the ability to have a colorbox gallery. It just opens up the one image. There's no longer the ability to view all images in a gallery and click through them or have a slideshow like my site is designed to have.

Comment: Finally I got it. It is working like a charm now. check out the latest changes. Add my code at the end of your "gallery light box setup" code

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, unfortunately it's still not working on my site. I tried to implement it and it doesn't resize the image. What it seems to do is to add scroll bars so that I can scroll around the huge image on my phone, but it's not really functional. It also seems to make things on the desktop not work as smoothly either. If you want to view my site with your added code, you can. I'll revert back to the previous in a couple of hours.

Comment: I checked out your website after 1 hour from your post, I did not see the changes I have recommended. Did you add it to "templatemo_script.js" file?

Comment: Ok to better explain what it was doing its like the window for the gallery was getting smaller as the screen was resized but the actual photos within that window weren't resizing. They were staying full-size so you had to scroll to see the full picture. Maybe there's something in my code elsewhere that makes it like that but for some reason the picture itself isn't being resized only the "frame" if you will.

Comment: And yes I added it to that file. I can add it back in to my website so you can take a look at it again. Just a moment.

Comment: I saw that. Add "scalePhotos:true" to colorbox setup like latest edit on my answer. This is my last trick, hope it helps :)

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't change anything. Thanks so much, though, for trying to help me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

I found this code referenced online when trying to look for a solution

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Make ColorBox responsive
    jQuery.colorbox.settings.maxWidth  = '100%';
    jQuery.colorbox.settings.maxHeight = '100%';

    // ColorBox resize function
    var resizeTimer;
    function resizeColorBox()
    {
        if (resizeTimer) clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
        resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                if (jQuery('#cboxOverlay').is(':visible')) {
                        jQuery.colorbox.load(true);
                }
        }, 300);
    }

    // Resize ColorBox when resizing window or changing mobile device orientation
    jQuery(window).resize(resizeColorBox);
    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", resizeColorBox, false);
</script>
```

I added it to the index.html file and it seems to make the colorbox photos responsive in that when viewing my site on a mobile device they are now sized to fit on that screen. However, it also is scaling my photos when viewing my website on a dekstop or a laptop. I'm curious if there might be a way to have this piece of code only work when a certain screen size is detected.